# Accessing @atlas_geometry in QgsExpression in QgsFeatureRequest

Tags: pyqgis

It seems evaluation of `@atlas_geometry` is always `null`

test code:

```
exp = QgsExpression('if(@atlas_geometry is null,1,0)') // always returns 1
rq = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)
```

`@atlas_geometry` within layer's expressions seems work fine though.

I have to do double spatial filtering across two layers so I come up with writing a predicate in PyQGIS for using in layer expression. Unfortunately it seems `@atlas_geometry` always returns null in my python code, despite it works fine in layer expression.

Can I access `@atlas_geometry` in my python code as if it's in layer's expression?